# Ensure variable is available before running filter code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I set a rootScope variable in my run block like so:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'numbersService', function($rootScope, numbersService) {
  numbersService.getAvailableCodes().$promise.then(function(data) {
    $rootScope.availableCodes = data.codes;
  });
}]);
```

I need `$rootScope.availableCodes` to be available in order for my filter to run properly. Here is the beginning of my filter code:

```
.filter('formatValue', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var availableCodes = $rootScope.availableCodes;
  ...
```

My problem is that since `$rootScope.availableCodes` is set based on an async call it is not guaranteed to be available when my filter runs (this filter appears in dozens of places throughout my HTML). How can I wait to run the rest of my filter logic until `$rootScope.availableCodes` is set?

Comment: duplicated [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609205/angularjs-promise-in-app-run)

Comment: A resolve in router would be best for this

Comment: @charlietfl, so move the code in my run block to a resolve within each route that needs access to it?

Comment: Would it be a lot of routes?

Comment: @charlietfl, it would be as this filter is used within several routes. I'm looking at answers such as this in order to build in some 'universal resolve' functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937751/angular-how-use-one-resolve-for-all-the-routes-of-my-application

Comment: Which router are you using? If it's ui-router can have one resolve in a parent state and all child states will inherit that resolve. Can also check if value is set in filter... and return original input until it is set